# É possível achar tons mais escuros/claros a partir de um hexadecimal?

Tags: javascript, css, hexadecimal

Dada uma cor qualquer na notação `Hexadecimal`, é possível achar a mesma em tons mais claros ou mais escuros? exemplo...

```css
    div {
      height: 50px;
      width: 150px;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 50px;
      margin-top:0px;
    }
    div:nth-child(1) {
      background: #5AAC56;
    }
    div:nth-child(2) {
      background: #338A2E;
    }
    div:nth-child(3) {
      background: #156711;
    }
```

```html
    <div>Cor gerada</div>
    <div>Cor original</div>
    <div>Cor gerada</div>
```

Comment: Deve ser possível, esse site faz isso https://highintegritydesign.com/tools/tinter-shader/

Comment: Opa vlw, vou dar uma olhada no código fonte, se eu conseguir alguma coisa posto aqui...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modelo apenas com CSS.

Fiz esse modelo que tem **apenas UMA Cor**, basta troca-la que toda a escala muda `div {background: #338A2E; /* qualque cor aqui */}`. A técnica é criar um pseudo elemento na cor Branco ou Preta por cima da cor original, e ir mudando a opacidade para fazer a escala.

```css
div {
height: 50px;
width: 150px;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
margin-top:10px;
background: #338A2E; /* qualque cor aqui */
position: relative;
}
div::before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}
div:nth-child(1)::before {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
div:nth-child(2)::before {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
div:nth-child(3)::before {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
div:nth-child(4)::before {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
div:nth-child(5)::before {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
div:nth-child(6)::before {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
div:nth-child(7)::before {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
div:nth-child(8)::before {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
div:nth-child(9)::before {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<div>0.1</div>
<div>0.2</div>
<div>0.3</div>
<div>0.4</div>
<div>0.5</div>
<div>0.6</div>
<div>0.7</div>
<div>0.8</div>
<div>0.9</div>
```

**Agora no Branco**

Basta trocar o `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);` por `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,  0.1);`

```css
div {
height: 50px;
width: 150px;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
margin-top:10px;
background: #338A2E; /* qualque cor aqui */
position: relative;
}
div::before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
}
div:nth-child(1)::before {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,  0.1);
}
div:nth-child(2)::before {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,  0.2);
}
div:nth-child(3)::before {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,  0.3);
}
div:nth-child(4)::before {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,  0.4);
}
div:nth-child(5)::before {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,  0.5);
}
div:nth-child(6)::before {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,  0.6);
}
div:nth-child(7)::before {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,  0.7);
}
div:nth-child(8)::before {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,  0.8);
}
div:nth-child(9)::before {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,  0.9);
}
```

```html
<div>0.1</div>
<div>0.2</div>
<div>0.3</div>
<div>0.4</div>
<div>0.5</div>
<div>0.6</div>
<div>0.7</div>
<div>0.8</div>
<div>0.9</div>
```

Comment: Sensacional, e realmente da certo, até para problemas em que o hexa fica muito nas extremidades, um algoritmo teria de pensar muito para identificar essa diferença, o que não ocorre com uma simples camada de opacidade, vlw @hugocsl.

Comment: @FelipeDuarte como eu não entendo muito de JS eu acabo sempre tentando resolver as coisas com CSS primeiro rss, as vezes da certo, como nesse caso, mas tem horas que é melhor 2 linhas de JS  :)

Answer (score 2):

Há uma maneira bem simples, mas que não oferece muito controle.

Para deixar mais escuro:

```
(corEmHex & 0xfefefe) >> 1
```

Para deixar mais claro:

```
(corEmHex & 0x7f7f7f) << 1
```

Se você deseja ter mais controle sobre o quão clara/escura a cor deve ficar, é melhor separar os valores RGB e trabalhar com eles individualmente.

[Referência do SO en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787124/programmatically-darken-a-hex-colour/1787193#1787193)

Comment: Possivelmente baseado em: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1787193/1452488

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Cem por cento baseado nela.

Comment: É sempre bom citar a fonte nesses casos para reconhecer o trabalho de quem elaborou a resposta e, também, para que os usuários tenham acesso a todas as outras respostas que também podem ser úteis.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Feito.

Comment: Muito interessante essa técnica.

Answer (score 1):

Felipe vou te passar 3 modelos que devem te ajudar com sua resposta.

1 - Vários tipos de **escalas de cor** (acho que é o mais perto que que vc quer, mas não consegui fazer funcionar no Snippet do StackOverflow)

https://codepen.io/stevepepple/pen/adRJaB?q=color+scaling&limit=all&type=type-pens

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2 - Capturar o **Average Color de uma imagem**. (Primeiro tem que converter a img em Base64) Ver no Snippet abaixo.

```js
    var rgb = getAverageRGB(document.getElementById('i'));
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+rgb.r+','+rgb.g+','+rgb.b+')';

function getAverageRGB(imgEl) {
    
    var blockSize = 5, // only visit every 5 pixels
        defaultRGB = {r:0,g:0,b:0}, // for non-supporting envs
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d'),
        data, width, height,
        i = -4,
        length,
        rgb = {r:0,g:0,b:0},
        count = 0;
        
    if (!context) {
        return defaultRGB;
    }
    
    height = canvas.height = imgEl.naturalHeight || imgEl.offsetHeight || imgEl.height;
    width = canvas.width = imgEl.naturalWidth || imgEl.offsetWidth || imgEl.width;
    
    context.drawImage(imgEl, 0, 0);
    
    try {
        data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    } catch(e) {
        /* security error, img on diff domain */alert('x');
        return defaultRGB;
    }
    
    length = data.data.length;
    
    while ( (i += blockSize * 4) < length ) {
        ++count;
        rgb.r += data.data[i];
        rgb.g += data.data[i+1];
        rgb.b += data.data[i+2];
    }
    
    // ~~ used to floor values
    rgb.r = ~~(rgb.r/count);
    rgb.g = ~~(rgb.g/count);
    rgb.b = ~~(rgb.b/count);
    
    return rgb;
    
}
```

```html
Setting the BODY's background to the average color in the following image:

<br><br>

<img id="i" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
```

Fonte: https://codepen.io/influxweb/pen/LpoXba

3 - Conseguir uma **paleta de cores a partir de uma Imagem**. Tem até extensão pro Chrome.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Link do Projeto no GitHub: https://github.com/unindented/palette-creator

Extensão: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/palette-creator/oolpphfmdmjbojolagcbgdemojhcnlod

*Artigo em Português para entender melhor como funciona a cor hexadecimal:*

http://serprogramador.com.br/artigos/topico/css/Como-entender-os-padroes-de-cores-RGB-RGBA-Hexadecimal

Comment: Muito bom! vou estudar cada item da resposta, a propósito percebi que o primeiro modelo que está no codepen, usa 4 bibliotecas externas jquery, lodash, chroma e d3, deve ser por isso que não funcionou aqui.

Comment: @FelipeDuarte pode se isso mesmo, não tinha visto. Vou fazer um modelo só em CSS pra vc ver. As vezes pode te ajudar tb, pq vc vai usar só uma cor e usar um ::before para fazer a variação.